why does it say "failed to create AR session"
Why does my application have 'failed to create an AR session'. what should i fix?
HERE IS MY CODE:
`
package com.example.spacify
 import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.View

class Furniture : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_furniture)

        val buttonCamera = findViewById<View>(R.id.testARFurniture)
        buttonCamera.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, CameraActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}

`
I tried changing my gradle version but nothing seems to work.
